# What is the order of the JoJo anime series?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

My friend recommended me to watch *JoJo's Bizzare Adventure*, but when I googled it I found there are many series.

What is the order of the anime?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the order of the events in the series it goes like this:

1. [JoJo no Kimyou na Bouken (TV)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/14719/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken_TV) (This covers the Battle Tendecy Arc and the Phantom Blood Arc.)
2. [JoJo no Kimyou na Bouken: Stardust Crusaders](http://myanimelist.net/anime/20899/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken__Stardust_Crusaders)
3. [JoJo no Kimyou na Bouken: Stardust Crusaders 2nd Season](http://myanimelist.net/anime/26055/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken__Stardust_Crusaders_2nd_Season)
4. [JoJo no Kimyou na Bouken: Diamond wa Kudakenai](http://myanimelist.net/anime/31933/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken__Diamond_wa_Kudakenai)
5. [Kishibe Rohan wa Ugokanai](https://myanimelist.net/anime/33191/Kishibe_Rohan_wa_Ugokanai) (OVA)
6. [JoJo no Kimyou na Bouken: Ougon no Kaze](https://myanimelist.net/anime/37991/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken__Ougon_no_Kaze)

All of the above are the main TV series. This anime also has the 90's version some movie, and an OVA.

1. [JoJo no Kimyou na Bouken (2000)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/665/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken_2000)
2. [JoJo no Kimyou na Bouken](http://myanimelist.net/anime/666/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken)

Comment: Kind of pointless mention the Phantom Blood OVA as it doesn't exist anymore. It was only shown in theaters and was so poorly recieved it never got a home release and all of the footage of it was destroyed aside for a few small boot-leg phone captures.

Answer (score 12):

The JoJo's Bizzare Adventure series (as in, the manga) as a whole is devided into 8 story arcs. 3 of these have been animated so far. I'm going to list these in order of release, but as far as order of viewing goes... Well, let's get to that when we get to that.
Also, it should be noted that all of these arcs, while sharing chronologial connetions (to a point), are rather self sustained and can be enjoyed even on their own.

The [1993 6 episode OVA](http://myanimelist.net/anime/666/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken) starts at the middle of the 3rd plot line.
The [2000 7 episode OVA](http://myanimelist.net/anime/665/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken_2000) presents the beginning of the 3rd plot line, up to where to pervious OVA starts.
Both of these are are a bit of a relic, differ grately in animation style and production as a while and, well the first one just oozes early 90s anime style. As a whole (and even on their own) they tell a rather self sustained story, but only a small part of it.

The 2012 television series is the one that actually starts the story from the beginning. The first 26 episode season covers story arcs [1 and 2](http://myanimelist.net/anime/14719/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken_TV). Afterwards, starting at 2014, the series covered the [3rd arc in 48 episodes](http://myanimelist.net/anime/20899/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken__Stardust_Crusaders). (So, basicly doing what the OVAs did in third of the episode count.) The next season, apparently starting at April 2016, is palled to start covering the [4th arc](http://myanimelist.net/anime/31933/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken__Diamond_wa_Kudakenai).

So, where to start... If you want to get the whole story, I suggest the television series. It follows the manga quite faithfuly and is quite coherent in its presentation.
However, if you want to get a quick feel for what you'll be getting into, I'd suggest either of the OVAs (depending if you perfer the 90s style, or a more modern style). These OVAs cover the (arguably) most popular story arc in the series in a relatively short time. If you decide you want more, the TV series should still be enjoyable as it covers a lot of things (not limited to the 2 first story arcs) that the OVAs skip.

There's also an [animated movie](http://myanimelist.net/anime/3603/JoJo_no_Kimyou_na_Bouken__Phantom_Blood) covering the 1st story arc. But it was apparently so bad that it was never officaly released outside theatres. From what I understand, there isn't a known, complete copy of the movie *anywhere*.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer isn't at the top.

Answer (score 4):

The order of the series is:

- JoJo's Bizarre Adventure Phantom Blood
- JoJo's Bizarre Adventure Battle Tendency
- JoJo's Bizarre Adventure Stardust Crusaders
- JoJo's Bizarre Adventure Diamond Is Unbreakable
- JoJo's Bizarre Adventure Vento Aureo
- JoJo's Bizarre Adventure Stone Ocean
- JoJo's Bizarre Adventure Steel Ball Run
- JoJo's Bizarre Adventure JoJolion

Part 9 isn't out and the creator says it might be the last JoJo series because so yeah

Comment: And what would this 'order' reflect? Chronological order? Release order? or something else all together?

Comment: @Dimitrimx Release order. Some parts of Stone Ocean occur before Stardust Crusaders.

Comment: Isn't it generational order?